# Get the 1-norm of a vector in Python

Tags: python, vector, norm

How can I calculate the 1-norm of the difference of two vectors, `||a - b||_1 = sum(|a_i - b_i|)` in Python?

```
a = [1,2,3,4]  
b = [2,3,4,5]

||a - b||_1 = 4
```

Comment: Could you clarify that a bit? It's not clear (to me, at least) which operation you're trying to perform ... It's not a 4D vector distance, and not a set intersection, so what is it?

Comment: Second that, no idea what you're trying to do here.

Comment: He probably means the 1-norm distance.

Answer (score 41):

Python has powerful built-in types, but **Python lists are not mathematical vectors or matrices**. You *could* do this with lists, but it will likely be cumbersome for anything more than trivial operations.

If you find yourself needing vector or matrix arithmetic often, the **standard in the field is [NumPy](http://scipy.org/NumPy/)**, which probably already comes packaged for your operating system the way Python also was.

I share the confusion of others about exactly what it is you're trying to do, but perhaps the **numpy.linalg.norm** function will help:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> b = numpy.array([2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> numpy.linalg.norm((a - b), ord=1)
4
```

To show how that's working under the covers:

```
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> b
array([2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> (a - b)
array([-1, -1, -1, -1])
>>> numpy.linalg.norm((a - b))
2.0
>>> numpy.linalg.norm((a - b), ord=1)
4
```

Answer (score 15):

In NumPy, for two vectors `a` and `b`, this is just

```
numpy.linalg.norm(a - b, ord=1)
```

Answer (score 10):

You appear to be asking for the sum of the differences between the paired components of the two arrays:

```
>>> A=[1,2,3,4]
>>> B=[2,3,4,5]
>>> sum(abs(a - b) for a, b in zip(A, B))
4
```

Comment: the l1 norm is what that is; it is a really obscure way of saying it, but in math you write it all the time.  The notation is `||x||`, which usually defaults to the euclidean norm (vector distance, in the physical sense), but `x / ||x||_1` would be probability of an item in `x`, while `x / ||x||_2` would be the unit vector

Comment: it goes back to the pythagorean theorem: the l1 norm would be a+b (manhattan distance), in the triangle, while the l2 norm would be the length of the hypotenuse

Answer (score 5):

It is not clear what exactly is required here, but here is my guess

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
b=[2,3,4,5]
def a_b(a,b):
    return sum(map(lambda a:abs(a[0]-a[1]), zip(a,b)))

print a_b(a,b)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using Numpy you can calculate any norm between two vectors using the linear algebra package.**

```
 import numpy as np
 a = np.array([[2,3,4])
 b = np.array([0,-1,7])
      
 # L1 Norm
 np.linalg.norm(a-b, ord=1)

 # L2 Norm
 np.linalg.norm(a-b, ord=2)

# L3 Norm
 np.linalg.norm(a-b, ord=3)

# Ln Norm
 np.linalg.norm(a-b, ord=n)
```

**Example:**

[image]